# Unix row to column format with string prefix and post fix

Tags: shell, unix

I have the requirement to convert row string data to column format and pre/postfix specific strings. The data string in file has 4 major fixed columns (separated by ";") and each column is further divided in two sections (separated by ":").

E.g.

Source data file:

```
A100:T100;B100:T200;A200:T300;B200:T400
```

Output from file should be:

```
TABa:BatchID=A100:TagId=T100:ProcId=1
TABb:BatchID=B100:TagId=T200:ProcId=2
TABc:BatchID=A200:TagId=T300:ProcId=3
TABd:BatchID=B200:TagId=T400:ProcId=4
```

Meanwhile I am trying with following code:

```
String="A100:T100;B100:T200;A200:T300;B200:T400"

> File.txt
for deploy in $(echo $String | tr ";" "\n")
do
   echo $deploy >> File.txt
done

cat File.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS=":" } NR==1{ print "TABa:BatchID="$1,$2 } NR==2{ print "TABb:BatchID="$1,$2 }'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (You will find that SO is a much friendlier place if you show that you have put some effort in.)

Comment: I added a sample piece of code I tried.

Comment: You could avoid the temporary file with: `echo $String | tr ";" "\n" | awk '…'` if you fix the `awk` script. You don't seem to be attempting to insert that TagId or ProcId, and it isn't clear why record one needs to be treated differently from record 2, and why the others should be ignored altogether.  'Tis curious that you have `BatchID` vs `TagId` and `ProcId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` handles this:

```
$ awk -F: '{sub(/\n/,""); printf "TAB%c:BatchID=%s:TagId=%s:ProcId=%i\n",(NR+96),$1,$2,NR }' RS=';' File.txt
TABa:BatchID=A100:TagId=T100:ProcId=1
TABb:BatchID=B100:TagId=T200:ProcId=2
TABc:BatchID=A200:TagId=T300:ProcId=3
TABd:BatchID=B200:TagId=T400:ProcId=4
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  This sets the field separator to a colon: `:`.
- `sub(/\n/,"")`

  This removes newline characters.
- `printf "TAB%c:BatchID=%s:TagId=%s:ProcId=%i\n",(NR+96),$1,$2,NR`

  This does all the work.  It makes use of the record number, `NR`, and the first and second fields and prints the output that you want.
- `RS=';'`

  This tells awk to use a semicolon, `;`, as the record separator.